# How to give temporary access to some files on internal storage to other applications?

Tags: android, permissions, android-intent

I have application A and application B, than I have some file on the A application and I want to make the file available for app B. The file is in the internal storage in the private app data. What should I do ? Is there some permission to give to the file ? is there some specific way of creating intents ???

how does work the process for these kinds of files, I mean if it was a file in the sdcard would be very easy ....

Comment: Why not put the file on the SD card? Is application A saving the file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use a [Content Provider](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/providers/content-providers.html) in your app.

From the Android Dev page:

> Content providers store and retrieve
>   data and make it accessible to all
>   applications. They're the only way to
>   share data across applications;
>   there's no common storage area that
>   all Android packages can access.

Of course, Application B will need to be aware of your provider and able to use it.